# hyperlink doesn’t work in Access form

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access form in which I am unsuccessful in formatting the record to be in hyperlink format.

The form is in datasheet-view format, which contains records with  a link to a website.   The form’s datasource is a select-query. The hyperlink is created with the following expression, which concantenates text and data, in order create a web link :

```
"#http://www.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?sort_by=status&tracknums_displayed=1&TypeOfInquiryNumber=T&loc=en_us&InquiryNumber1=" & [T].[tracking_number] & "&track.x=0&track.y=0#"
```

I tried setting the property-sheet format field to “hyperlink” , but it automatically changes to “hy"perli"n\k”, in both the query-design view, and form-design-view.

please advise what I need to do in order to have the form output the records in hyperlink format, so I can just click on the website link and it will open up in a web browser

thanks very much in advance,
Nathaniel, Access 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IsHyperlink property for the textbox (format tab) , once again, these are a nuisance to edit. If you create a form based on a table with a hyperlink field, the control created for the hyperlink field will be set up as a link.

More on IsHyperlink: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196153(office.11).aspx

Paste something like this into the textbox to see it working:

```
clickme#http://www.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?sort_by=status&tracknums_displayed=1&TypeOfInquiryNumber=T&loc=en_us&InquiryNumber1=123456&track.x=0&track.y=0#
```

Comment: Remou, Once again were super helpful.  I can not thank you enough